# Set different numbering for sections & subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, chapters, document-classes

So I have been working on my masters thesis and used a template I found. Now my prof told me that I may not use chapters in this thesis which lead to me reworking the structure.

So I switched around:

- chapter->section
- section->subsection
- subsection->subssubsection

But now the numbering is totally weird. I know that changing the document file (currently MastersDoctoralThesis) would help me solve the problem but as everything else is formatted with the documentclass in mind I do not wanna change that one. The result I wanna get would be:

## 1. Section

### 1.1 Subsection

#### 1.1.1 Subsubsection

Currently I am getting:

## 0.1 Section

### 0.1.1 Subsection

#### Subsubsection

I have been putting together a minimal working example to hopefully find some help:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/jrtbbmdvhphv

Would it be easier to format everything else for like an article document class or would it be easier to change the numbering? As I am using a lot of literature, graphs, abrevations, and tables This has been an awesome template up until now and I am really stressed by the idea of making my own...

I really wanna thank you wholeheartedly for any help!

Comment: This class apparently has `\providecommand{\baseclass}{book}`. Try `\newcommand{\baseclass}{article}` _before_ `\documentclass`

Comment: Alternatively, you can try  to add in the preamble `\counterwithout{section}{chapter}`, or if it doesn't work, `\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithout{section}{chapter}}`.

Comment: `\providecommand{\baseclass}{book}`
Puts out some errors (that apparently do not have a negative influence)

`\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithout{section}{chapter}}` does work! I added `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` in a row below that to also get the numbering for the subsubsection and now its like I want it.

So both answers work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Indeed, the class never checks if chapters are defined which leads to errors if they're not. You might very vell need to check your headers and other layout elements. They will still assume that you are using chapters…

Comment: The `memoir` class (a superset of `report` and `book`) has an `article` option which typesets book-like code (including chapters) like an article (changing chapters to sections, sections to subsections, etc.).